# How to work with Skype for business in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, skype-for-business

I have a requirement from my client that we need to integrate Skype for business option in my asp.net MVC website

I am quite new to Microsoft SDK's, Can any one suggest me by step by step procedure how to go through it, and any of the working sample codes, please

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Hi! Can you specify a little bit more about what do you need to do? Skype has a lot of functions which you are able to integrate.

Comment: I need to schedule a meeting request with skype for business using c# , I need to include an skype for business URL in email to user. so clients can meet on that URL for their meetings.

I want to know what are required to do this and a step by step process please